# Is there any way to refresh customer access tokens in magento 2

Tags: authentication, magento2, access-token, bearer-token, refresh-token

In Magento 2, customer tokens expire after an hour and the user is forced to login again. Is there a way to refresh the token?

The docomentation of mangeto does not specify such a mechanism. I am developing a mobile application and I want the customer to be logged as longer as possilbe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could increase cookie lifetime which can be found in Admin Backoffice at *Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Default Cookie Settings section*
Make sure you switch the scope from *Default Config* to either *Website* or *Store View* if you have multiple stores.

See [Magento docs](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/customers/customer-accounts/configure/customer-online-options.html) for more info.

*Edit:*

I just realised that you are talking about OAuth tokens and not sessions. If that's the case, you still need to edit one value in config, which can be found at *Stores > Configuration > Services > OAuth > Access Token Expiration section*

[Docs](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/tutorials/inventory/create-customer/#generate-the-customers-access-token).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is the solution I went with. Still feels like a workaround to me without a proper refresh token mechanism, but at this point of time it does the job. Thank you again.